# Emulate Windows-style file locking on Linux and OS/X

Tags: c, linux, file-locking

I'm trying to get file-locking semantics on Linux that are close to what Windows offers for the purpose of not deleting cache files while they're open by a separate process. My program creates various temporary cache files that I want to delete when it closes, however multiple instances might run at the same time and I don't want to delete a file that's in use by another instance, because it will break semantics - the cache file is opened by name at various points and if deleted, that will break. I know that Linux won't physically delete the file until all open handles are closed, but I still need to open it by name.

The name of each file uniquely identifies the contents, i.e. I know that if I need data X, it's in the cache file named hash(X), so it doesn't matter if the current instance is the one creating it, or if I'm reusing a file created by another instance. Obviously it's not exactly the hash of the data, since if I had the data, I wouldn't need cache files, but suffice to say that reusing cache files is what I want.

My problem is that I haven't found a race-free way to lock the file with flock after opening it. Between those two calls another process might finish and run a cache cleanup operation that deletes the file I've just created. I don't need mandatory locking like on Windows, since it's only my program accessing those files, but I do need a way to keep instances from stepping on each other.

Edit: I'm using C.

Comment: You don't state a language/environment? Maybe use a counting semaphore.

Comment: Look at mtime and ctime; if you avoid deleting files that were created or modified in the past minute you're fine. Or the past day perhaps.

Comment: This is very Linux-specific, but is known to work in similar situations. Install a `SIGIO` handler (empty function is fine), and use [`fcntl(fileno(handle), F_SETLEASE, F_WRLCK)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) to take a write lease on the file. It will only succeed if the file is not open by any other process. (This does require that the file is owned by the same user as the running process, or that the process is running with superuser privileges.) If you do get the file lease, `unlink()`/`remove()` the file name and `fclose(handle)`; otherwise just `fclose(handle)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to delete a file that's in use by another instance

You *cannot* delete a file used by another process (or even the same process). You can delete the directory entry (or rather *a* directiry entry, as there may be more than one) that points to that file, but the file itself will remain live for as long as it's kept open by *any* process. Files in Linux are reference-counted, that's what making it work.

An easy method to collaboratively "lock" a file by name would be this:

```
    char new_filename[FILENAME_SIZE] = "busy_";
    link (filename, strcat(new_filename, filename));
    fd = open(new_filename, "r");
    if (fd) {
        ......
        close (fd);
    }
    unlink (new_filename);
```

One does *not* check the result of `link`. If everyone does this to open a file, and cleanup only unlinks the *original* name, you are set.

Comment: Yes, yes I know. That's why I specifically said I still need to open it by name from the same process. Basically, what happens is that one part of the program generates the file name and opens it, and keeps it open for the duration that it's used. Then another part opens it again, by name. If the directory entry is deleted between those two points, the second open will fail.

Comment: Sorry missed this part: "the cache file is opened by name at various points". That looks like the real problem. Why do that? Why not have a per-process registry of open files?